# Frozen discard pile for Canasta

Tags: canasta

For the initial meld with the pile frozen, what are the rules for picking up the discard pile? If the minimum meld is 120, is the meld plus two naturals needed to pick up the pile, or just two naturals and a wild card and be able to use this as part of my meld.  I have always played that in order to pick up the pile I need the meld plus a natural pair in order to pick up a frozen pile, but just lately I've seen it where the person was able to pick up the frozen pile with 2 naturals plus wild card while the pile is frozen. Which version is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have enough cards in hand in addition to the top card to make your initial play in order to pick up the discard pile. As long as you have all the cards to meet the points for the initial meld you can take it otherwise, you can't

[Canasta Rules](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/canasta/#:%7E:text=A%20frozen%20discard%20pile%20is,same%20rank%20from%20their%20hand.)

> A frozen discard pile is unfrozen only by being taken. When the discard pile is topped by a wild card or a black three, at least one natural card must be discarded on top of the pile before the pile may be taken. Then, a player may take that card (and the pile) only with a natural pair of the same rank from their hand. Before touching the discard pile, the player should show the pair (together with any additional cards if needed to meet the minimum count of an initial meld).